# Unable to run MongoDB Community v6.1 after installation on Apple Silicon Mac

Tags: mongodb

I have Mac with an Apple Silicon Chip running Monterey 12.6 and I'm trying to install MongoDB community v6.1 on it by following the steps laid out in these docs.
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

After completing all the steps in the installation, I am trying to run MongoDB as a background process (using the command `mongod --config /opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf --fork`), but rather than seeing a message saying it is waiting for connections on port 27017, instead I see the following error message.

```
about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
forked process: 16461
ERROR: child process failed, exited with 100
To see additional information in this output, start without the "--fork" option.
```

Has anyone seen this before and discovered how to fix it? I have completed all the previous steps in the installation from the docs linked above.

Thanks

UPDATE: I was able to view the output to the log file. I am pasting it below. Hopefully this provides more context. It looks like Mongo is trying to create a file in a read only directory.

```
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.130-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20698,   "ctx":"-","msg":"***** SERVER RESTARTED *****"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.132-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"-","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":17},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":6,"maxWireVersion":17},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.133-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.144-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648602, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen in use."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","namespace":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"ShardSplitDonorService","namespace":"config.tenantSplitDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.147-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":5945603, "ctx":"main","msg":"Multi threading initialized"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4615611, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"MongoDB starting","attr":{"pid":23320,"port":27017,"dbPath":"/System/Volumes/Data/data/db","architecture":"64-bit","host":"Ahmeds2021MBP14.ht.home"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23352,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Unable to resolve sysctl {sysctlName} (number) ","attr":{"sysctlName":"hw.cpufrequency"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23351,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"{sysctlName} unavailable","attr":{"sysctlName":"machdep.cpu.features"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23403,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Build Info","attr":{"buildInfo":{"version":"6.0.1","gitVersion":"32f0f9c88dc44a2c8073a5bd47cf779d4bfdee6b","modules":[],"allocator":"system","environment":{"distarch":"aarch64","target_arch":"aarch64"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.148-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":51765,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Operating System","attr":{"os":{"name":"Mac OS X","version":"21.6.0"}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.149-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":21951,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Options set by command line","attr":{"options":{"config":"/opt/homebrew/etc/mongod.conf","net":{"bindIp":"127.0.0.1, ::1","ipv6":true},"processManagement":{"fork":true},"storage":{"dbPath":"/System/Volumes/Data/data/db"},"systemLog":{"destination":"file","logAppend":true,"path":"/opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log"}}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.150-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.150-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":5693100, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Asio socket.set_option failed with std::system_error","attr":{"note":"acceptor TCP fast open","option":{"level":6,"name":261,"data":"00 04 00 00"},"error":{"what":"set_option: Invalid argument","message":"Invalid argument","category":"asio.system","value":22}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.151-04:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20557,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"DBException in initAndListen, terminating","attr":{"error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.151-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4784900, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stepping down the ReplicationCoordinator for shutdown","attr":{"waitTimeMillis":15000}}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.152-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":4794602, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Attempting to enter quiesce mode"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.152-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":6371601, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FLE Crud thread pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.152-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784901, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MirrorMaestro"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.152-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784902, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the WaitForMajorityService"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":20562,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutdown: going to close listening sockets"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784905, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the global connection pool"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784906, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the FlowControlTicketholder"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":20520,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.153-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4784918, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ReplicaSetMonitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"SHARDING", "id":4784921, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the MigrationUtilExecutor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22582,   "ctx":"MigrationUtil-TaskExecutor","msg":"Killing all outstanding egress activity."}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"COMMAND",  "id":4784923, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the ServiceEntryPoint"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.154-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784925, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down free monitoring"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784927, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the HealthLog"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784928, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the TTL monitor"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":6278511, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down the Change Stream Expired Pre-images Remover"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":4784929, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Acquiring the global lock for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.155-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"-",        "id":4784931, "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Dropping the scope cache for shutdown"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.156-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":20565,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Now exiting"}
{"t":{"$date":"2022-09-18T20:14:46.156-04:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23138,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Shutting down","attr":{"exitCode":100}}
```

UPDATE 2:
These are the contents of my configuration file.

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /opt/homebrew/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1, ::1
  ipv6: true
```

Comment: What do you get without `--fork` as indicated in the error message? Did you check the log file?

Comment: There's no output in the terminal when I run it without `--fork` . How do I see what's in the log file?

Comment: see: "error":"IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /System/Volumes/Data/data/db"

Comment: Do you know how to configure it to use another directory instead? And do you know which directory would be best?

Comment: Does the mongod user has write permissions on `/System/Volumes/Data/data/db`

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Solution 3 on this link solved my problem.
https://solutionschecker.com/questions/read-only-file-system-when-attempting-mkdir-datadb-on-mac-closed/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your link is now broken and your solution is lost to the community

Comment: You're right. I marked this questions as a duplicate and linked the relevant question on Stack Overflow.